# Twitter Bootstrap Dropdown selected Open and Stay Active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

```
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="/"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Dashboard</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-caret-square-o-down"></i> Person <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="@Url.Action("index", "person")" class="person-list">Person list</a></li>
                    <li><a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "person")">Update Person</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

When I click and am on "Person list" page, how to keep class="dropdown" stay opened.
I've been struggling to do that. If anyone knows, please share.

Comment: What do you mean to stay opened? Can you explain what happens before and after?

Comment: before "dropdown-menu" is hidden.  when you click "Person", it will display. And when you click "Person List", the "dropdown-menu" will be hidden again.  my question is how to stay opened ul.dropdown-menu when I click submenu item "Person List"

Comment: can you set this up in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)